# How to code more than 2 ...extends AsyncTask .doInBackground() onPostExecute() within an Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

By the time android apps **onStart**(),it would **execute HttpRequestTask**. I have done this part and it **works fine**.

After the apps open and display data,needs to click on a **submit button to POST** some data to spring rest web service.In my mind,I think I might need to write another extends AsyncTask ,doInBackground and onPostExecute

**What should I code so that system could differentiate extends AsyncTask ,doInBackground and onPostExecute within same Activity?**

```
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    new HttpRequestTask().execute();
}



private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Item>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Item> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //....some code


}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<PickerItemDetail> pickerList) {
    //.....come code and logic

}

}
```

Comment: It's simple. Create Another class with different name in activity and extend it as async task, same as you do with the one posted in question. Then call it where you require it to, same as you call in onStatrt()

Comment: All the preExecute(), onPostExecute(), doInBackground() will be the methods of relevant classes. They won't interfere with each other.